# Scraper prints the first row only even with a loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

having some problems with be able to scrape the whole table from that url. It only manages to scrape the first row and leaving out the rest, could any one help or point me in the right direction please

My code is;

```
    import urllib2
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup


    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.live-footballontv.com/live-englishfootball-on-tv.html').read())

    for row in soup('table', {'class': 'gridtable'})[0].tbody('tr')[1:]:
        tds = row('td')

        print tds[0].string, tds[1].string, tds[2].string, tds[3].string, tds[4].string,
```

And heres the error;

```
      Tue 4th Feb Fulham v Sheffield United  FA Cup&nbsp;4th Round Replay 19:45           ITV4&nbsp;/&nbsp;ITV4 HD
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/owner/PycharmProjects/Football TV Guide App/TVGuide.py", line 11,   in <module>
      print tds[0].string, tds[1].string, tds[2].string, tds[3].string, tds[4].string,  ths[0].string
      IndexError: list index out of ran
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.live-footballontv.com/live-english-  football-on-tv.html').read())
    for row in soup('table', {'class': 'gridtable'})[0].tbody('tr'):
        ths = row('th')
        for th in ths:
            print th.string,
            print ',',
        tds = row('td')
        for td in tds:
            print td.string,
            print ',',
        print
```